# Solve the Integral: $\int{\sqrt{8y-x^2}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int{\sqrt{8y-x^2}}dx$$

For which I don't understand clearly how to work with root values.

What I've tried:
$$
\int{\sqrt{8y-x^2}dx} = \int{(8y-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx} \\
= \frac{(8y-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}\int{(8y-x^2)dx} \\
= \frac{(8y-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}(-\frac{x^3}{3}) \\
= -\frac{2}{3}(8y-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac{x^3}{3}) \\
= -\frac{2}{9}(8y-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}x^3
$$

Is that correct?

Comment: After some practice, you'll yourself realize that in general $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ requires the substitution $x=a\sin t$. You should makes notes on such types of patterns as they'll be handy in bigger problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if we use the substitution, $x=\sqrt{8y}\sin u$, then the integrand can be easily reduced to:

$$I=\int \sqrt{8y-x^2} dx = \sqrt{8y} \int \cos u \sqrt{8y-8y\sin^2 u} \,du=8y \int \cos^2 u \,du$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: i think there is an absolut value missing

Comment: $$\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}=\sqrt{\cos^2(u)}=|\cos(u)|$$

Answer (score 2):

this isn't correct, Substitute $$x=\sqrt{8y}\sin(t)$$

Comment: How did you come about that substitution?

Comment: i have a Collection of some substitutions of integrals of These types

Comment: Is is a document that you could possibly email to me?

Comment: what kind of document do you mean? about substitutions?

Comment: yes, as you mentions in your previous comment.